# Regex match string containing digits and ends with x

Tags: python, regex

I had just recently started using regex in python, so sorry if it's too trivial. I'm trying to extract string that consists of digits and ends with letter x.
For example from input asdx12x4
I want to get 12x.

I tried

```
import re
text = "asdx12x4"
result = re.findall("\d+x$", text)
print (result)
```

However result is such:

```
[]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: remove the `$`, `x` is not the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re
text = "asdx12x4"
result = re.findall(r'\d+x', text)
print(result)
```

This should work - just have to change the regex